# Changing Tabbar item title programmatically in viewDidLoad()

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I am trying to change the title of the tab item through the below code where I have to write that code in awakeFormNib() however due to some circumstances, I have to change the title in viewdidLoad(). I am using Swift.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.title = NSLocalizedString("Hello World", tableName: "xxx", comment: "");
}
```

Comment: I know there is a self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items which is [Anyobject] how to access each item

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did it using the below code in viewdidload()

```
if let downcastStrings = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items as? [UITabBarItem]
        {
            downcastStrings[0].title = "Hi"
        }
```